# How to query based on a list of DBRef field in Spark SQL

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-java

I have a mongo database that contains a list of DBRef objects. I am converting this collection into a data frame in spark.

[image]

This gives the below error. Does anyone know how to resolve this error ??

EDIT:: Conversion to dataframe gives following error -> *org.codehaus.janino.InternalCompilerException: Two non-abstract methods "public int scala.collection.TraversableOnce.size()" have the same parameter types, declaring type and return type*

Answer (score 3):

The error got resolved after upgrading the version of "org.codehaus.janino" to 3.0.9 (previously, I was using 3.0.8).